# Kubuntu 19.10 iwlwifi error causing system hang

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, 19.10, iwlwifi

Update : The problem seems to be in kernel 5.3.0-24, while booting into 23 it is working fine.

From today my Kubuntu 19.10 system is hanging when it tries to connect to wifi.  At the boot time it shows this error :

```
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
```

and then says

```
loaded firmware version 29.62a39462.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

The Intel driver was updated two days back and after this error when I tried to open the driver manager it doesn't work - just sits there saying collecting information about your system.

I tried removing the module and loading it again, it doesn't work. Couldn't find anything on the web to see how I can install or repair this.

### Update :

### `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi`

### `dmesg | grep iwl`

`[   22.928487] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   22.928487] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7906:7773a757
[   23.658864] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[   24.660202] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.62a39462.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.790152] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
[   24.814431] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: d4:25:8b:cd:23:14
[   24.848669] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   24.863488] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0`

I had enabled logging in without password and disabled auto connecting to wifi and the network applet used to show the available networks even,  when I click on connect to any one of them and give the password for kwallet, the system hangs immediately and I had to shutdown with the power switch.

### `journalctl | grep iwlwifi`

`Dec 10 07:57:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
Dec 10 07:57:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7906:7773a757
Dec 10 07:57:15 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
Dec 10 07:57:15 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.62a39462.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Dec 10 07:57:15 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
Dec 10 07:57:15 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: d4:25:8b:cd:23:14
Dec 10 07:57:15 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Dec 10 07:57:33 prajeesh-HPLPT NetworkManager[1127]: <info>  [1575944853.7311] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)`

### `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

### `grep iwlwifi /var/log/kern.log`

output with both working and hanging,

```
Dec  8 09:16:27 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   16.913593] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Dec  8 09:16:27 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   17.142880] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
Dec  8 09:16:27 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   17.164525] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: <address>
Dec  8 09:16:27 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   17.325932] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Dec  8 09:48:14 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [ 1947.490754] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Dec  8 09:48:39 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [ 1971.752157] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Dec  8 09:50:23 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [ 2076.381356] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Dec  8 09:51:33 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [ 2146.322949] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Dec  8 09:51:46 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [ 2159.340660] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Dec  9 07:43:50 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   21.236664] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Dec  9 07:43:50 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   21.532119] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
Dec  9 07:43:50 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   21.551705] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: <address>
Dec  9 07:43:50 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   21.626820] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Dec  9 12:49:32 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [13409.652057] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   20.099761] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   20.099761] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7906:7773a757
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   22.385800] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   22.502088] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.62a39462.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   22.703367] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   22.728114] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: <address>
Dec 10 07:40:13 prajeesh-HPLPT kernel: [   22.826500] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

-- And hung

Comment: The driver iwlwifi will report that it tried and failed to load a firmware file repeatedly until it finds and loads the suitable file. By themselves, the messages above are not harmful nor very informative. Please run: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and paste the result here and give us the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I see no evidence that the cause of the hang is iwlwifi nor its firmware. What do you see in dmesg after the timestamp [22.826500]? It may have been logrotated into /var/log/dmesg.0.

Comment: Here it is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PMG8mmZn6w/  The hanging happens only when I try to enable wifi or try to connect to any wireless network. With wifi disabled it is working fine on LAN.  I suspected vbox also but didn't try uninstalling it.

Comment: Seems like the kernal 5.3.0.-24 is having the issue.  I booted into the 23 and it works fine.

Comment: I suggest that you file a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: I went to the launchpad to report a bug and it drove me crazy through the labyrinth and still haven't figured out where the actual bug reporting page is. Given up.

Comment: Please start here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same Problem. My workaround so far, switch back to Kernel version 5.3.0-23-generic. Now it works as expected.

Comment: Seems like the kernal 5.3.0.-24 is having the issue

Comment: I suggest that you file a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.